# Ajax does not respond correctly

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an Ajax request from a thymleaf page. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982683/spring-mvc-3-2-thymeleaf-ajax-fragments).

Here is my html page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <script>
        function sendURL() {
            var url = '/updatePing';
            console.log("URI sent :)")  

            $("#resultsBlock").load(url);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Ping setup</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${ping}" th:method="post" th:action="@{/updatePing}">
              bla
              bla 
              bla
              <button id="submit-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="sendURL()">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div id="resultsBlock">
  </div>

  </div>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect that, after pushing button the js function (`sendURL()`) get called and then it sends the params to my controller. This part is working as well

but the answer which comes from controller does not place in the `<div id="resultsBlock">`

here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updatePing", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updatePing(@ModelAttribute PingDTO pingDTO) throws  Exception{
        PingRequestValidation pv=new PingRequestValidation();
        if(pv.checkPingRequestValidation(pingDTO.getUrl())){

            return "fragments/success";
        }
        else
            return "fragments/failure"; 
    }
```

The problem is, the controller exactly presents the success and failure pages,
meanwhile i expect that these fragments get presented in the  `resultsBlock` tag, in the main page.

So how can i fix this problem?

Comment: When form submits page will reload.

Comment: Are you saying you don't need anything sent from form? If not...no need to even use a form. Otherwise submit whole form with ajax and prevent default submit

Comment: @charlietfl ok i change the type to button, but now i get an 405 error.
i think, i am sending a post request using js in a wrong way. can u give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To submit whole form using ajax, remove the `onclick` on button and create a submit handler using jQuery

```
$(function(){
   $('#formId').on('submit', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();// stop browser submitting from
       var data = $(this).serialize();
       $.post('/updatePing', data , function(response){
             $("#resultsBlock").html(response);
       }).fail(function(){
             alert('Something went wrong')
       });
   });
});
```