# Using ajax in thymleaf, update only part of form

Tags: thymeleaf

I use SpringBoot, Thymeleaf.

I want to update the value only for part of form in update page.

```
<form id="form" class="needs-validation col-sm-6" th:action="@{'/user/edit/' + ${userInfo.id}}" th:object="${userInfo}" method="post" novalidate>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${userInfo.id}"/>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <h4 id="name" th:text="${userInfo.name}" th:value="${userInfo.name}"></h4>
        <input type="hidden" name="name" th:value="${userInfo.name}"/>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nickname">Nickname</label>
        <input id="nickname" type="text" name="nickname" th:value="${userInfo.nickname}" placeholder="enter nickname" required minlength="2">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="volunteerTime">Volunteer Time</label>
        <span id="volunteerTime" th:text="${userInfo.volunteerTime}+'hour'" name="volunteerTime" th:value="${userInfo.volunteerTime}"></span>

        <input type="text" size="5px" placeholder="hour"/>
        <button type="button" name="action" value="plus" onclick="ajax()">plus</button>
        <button type="button" name="action" value="minus" onclick="ajax()">minus</button>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="update">
    </div>
</form>
```

The "volunteerTime" section of the above code seeks to update and show values added to existing data according to the number entered.

The same goes for Minus.

[image: Here is current page]

Comment: Here is one possible approach relating to your general question - [Thymeleaf fragments with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982683/spring-mvc-3-2-thymeleaf-ajax-fragments). Typically, Thymeleaf and Ajax don't really overlap/interact (in my experience). They can certainly coexist, though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Then, can I solve the above problem with thymeleaf alone?