# Thymeleaf and Spring Boot - adding attributes to the model. What is the correct way?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, mapping, thymeleaf

I am trying to find a better way to set values to thymeleaf template, because I have a feeling the way I do it is wrong.

Say I have a controller with two mappings:

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String getSearchPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("weatherRequest", new WeatherRequest());
        model.addAttribute("weatherResponse", new WeatherResponse());
        model.addAttribute("temperature_real");
        model.addAttribute("temperature_feels");
        model.addAttribute("humidity");
        model.addAttribute("pressure");
        return "index";
    }
```

and

```
@PostMapping("/getWeather")
    public String getWeatherForCity(@ModelAttribute("weatherRequest") WeatherRequest request, Model model) throws JsonProcessingException {

        WeatherResponse response = weatherService.getWeatherData(request.getZipCode());
        model.addAttribute("weatherResponse", new WeatherResponse());
        model.addAttribute("temperature_real", response.mainWeatherData.temperature);
        model.addAttribute("temperature_feels", response.mainWeatherData.temperatureFeels);
        model.addAttribute("humidity", response.mainWeatherData.humidity);
        model.addAttribute("pressure", response.mainWeatherData.pressure);
        return "index";
```

`@GetMapping("/")` is for my home page, `@PostMapping("/getWeather")` is for when the button is clicked, so that i gather weather data for the entered zip code.

**It looks to me weird, that I am adding the attributes twice**, but it works.
However it **does not work** when I am trying to change template so that the form is only  rendered when the `mainWeatherData` is not null.

the relevant `index.html` part you can find below).

This is the part of the `index.html` that is changed.

```
<div>
    <form th:action="@{/getWeather}" method="post" th:object="${weatherRequest}">
        <label>Enter the postal code:</label>
        <input id="search" name="searchInput" th:field="*{zipCode}"/>
        <button  type="submit">Check weather</button>
    </form>
    <form >
        <div>
            <p>Temperature:<label th:text="${temperature_real}"></label></p>
            <p>Feels like:<label th:text="${temperature_feels}"></label></p>
            <p>Humidity:<label th:text="${humidity}"></label></p>
            <p>Pressure:<label th:text="${pressure}"></label></p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The whole form is not rendered both before I fetched the data and after the `mainWeatherData` is no more null.

This I am adding to the second form to render it when the weather data is not null:

`<form th:if="${weatherResponse.mainWeatherData != null}">`

- Main question: how can i improve adding the attributes in my controller.
- Second question: how do I make it render form in thymeleaf when the data is there.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mistaken in your feelings. There are a few more useful ways of the example you're trying to write, **I will show you my simple and popular usage:**

```java
public class WeatherRequest {

    private String zipCode;

    public WeatherRequest() {
    }

    // getter / setter ..
}
```

```java
public class WeatherResponse {

    private String temperatureReal;
    private String temperatureFeels;
    private String humidity;
    private String pressure;

    public WeatherResponse() {
    }

    // getter/setter ..
}
```

```java
@Controller
public class WeatherController {

   @GetMapping("/")
   public String getSearchPage(Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("weatherRequest", new WeatherRequest());
      return "weather-search";
   }

   @PostMapping("/getWeather")
   public String getWeatherForCity(Model model, WeatherRequest weatherRequest) {
      model.addAttribute("weatherRequest", weatherRequest);
      model.addAttribute("weatherResponses", getWeatherResponse(weatherRequest.getZipCode()));
      return "weather-search";
   }

   private List<WeatherResponse> getWeatherResponses(String zipCode) {
      List<WeatherResponse> weatherResponses = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
         WeatherResponse weatherResponse = new WeatherResponse();
         weatherResponse.setTemperatureReal("A" + i + ": " + zipCode);
         weatherResponse.setTemperatureFeels("B" + i + ": " + zipCode);
         weatherResponse.setHumidity("C" + i + ": " + zipCode);
         weatherResponse.setPressure("D" + i + ": " + zipCode);
         weatherResponses.add(weatherResponse);
      }
      return weatherResponses;
   }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <form th:action="@{/getWeather}" method="post" th:object="${weatherRequest}">
        <label>Enter the postal code:</label>
        <input th:field="*{zipCode}" />
        <button type="submit">Check Weather</button>
    </form>
    <div th:if="${!weatherResponses.isEmpty()}">
        <div th:each="weatherResponse: ${weatherResponses}">
            <p>Temperature:<label th:text="${weatherResponse.temperatureReal}"></label></p>
            <p>Feels Like:<label th:text="${weatherResponse.temperatureFeels}"></label></p>
            <p>Humidity:<label th:text="${weatherResponse.humidity}"></label></p>
            <p>Pressure:<label th:text="${weatherResponse.pressure}"></label></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*In Thymeleaf, iteration is achieved by using the `th:each` attribute.*

You can go further. For example, when you click on search, you can make an **`Ajax`** request and update the results instantly, etc.

If you use **`Ajax`** request, the `weatherRequest` in the `getWeatherForCity()` method will not be needed.

**This example links will show how to make use of `Thymeleaf Fragments` to reuse some common parts of a site:**

- [Working with Fragments in Thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-fragments)
- [Spring MVC 3.2 Thymeleaf Ajax Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982683/spring-mvc-3-2-thymeleaf-ajax-fragments)
- [Spring Boot / Thymeleaf: Fragments via Ajax](https://www.marcelustrojahn.com/2016/08/spring-boot-thymeleaf-fragments-via-ajax/)