# How to change Thymeleaf fragments dynamically depending on the href link

Tags: java, spring, templates, thymeleaf

I want to build a page with Thymeleaf fragments, which are rendered dynamically depending on the followed link.
And I have an issue with resolving fragments names in runtime through the Spring controller.

Here is the minimal reproductive example to show what I mean.

---

I have `list.html` page with two links **List 1** and **List 2** with pic and code as below:

[image: Links]

```html
<body>
  <button type="button"><a th:href="${'/lists/list1'}">List 1</a></button>
  <button type="button"><a th:href="${'/lists/list2'}">List 2</a></button>

  <!-- This doesn't work, the include is not resolved correctly -->
  <th:block th:include="'fragments/lists/' + ${fragmentName}
                        + ' :: ' + ${fragmentName}"></th:block>

  <!-- However static include works well -->
  <th:block th:include="fragments/lists/list1 :: list1"></th:block>
</body>
```

The related Spring controller looks as:

```java
@GetMapping("lists")
public String getListsPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("fragmentName", "listAll");
    return "lists";
}

@GetMapping("lists/list1")
public String getAllItems(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("list1", itemService.getList1());
    model.addAttribute("fragmentName", "list1");
    return "lists";
}

@GetMapping("lists/list2")
public String getAllItems(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("list2", itemService.getList2());
    model.addAttribute("fragmentName", "list2");
    return "lists";
}
```

The problem that `fragmentName` is not being resolved at runtime and it throws `TemplateInputException` exception:

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
  template ['fragments/lists/' + ${fragmentName} + '], template might not exist
  or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
  (template: "lists" - line 38, col 11)
```

At the same time static block works correctly as shown in `list.html` page code.

Please don't suggest me [Spring MVC 3.2 Thymeleaf Ajax Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982683/spring-mvc-3-2-thymeleaf-ajax-fragments), I don't want to use AJAX, I found the current solution of returning the fragment name   using controller very clear and simple for my case.

Probably I can use [Fragment Expressions](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/451), but I am not sure how exactly.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: How you want change title dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would express the syntax like this:

```
<th:block th:include="~{${'fragments/lists/' + fragmentName} :: ${fragmentName}}"></th:block>
```

Comment: Appreciate your assistance, it works like magic